# Using Data URL's in Javascript causing HTTP GET request

Tags: javascript, image, http, request

Using data url in javascript to reduce HTTP requests but I'm still seeing them.

```
Request URL: data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAAN...
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK (from memory cache)
Referrer Policy: same-origin
```

Am I doing something wrong? I thought the point of Data URL's was to reduce the number of HTTP requests. This is my javascript:

```
  function loadLegendImage(imageData, control) {
    const image = new Image();

    image.onload = () => {
      control.legendImage = image;
      markLayerChanged(control);
    };

    image.src = `data:image/png;base64, ${imageData}`;
  }
```

The drawing is done later..
Any advice?

Comment: It's not an HTTP request

Comment: It looks like it's loading the request/result from memory directly (from your Status Code `200 OK (from memory cache)`) rather than actually making a network request. Can you verify it's making a network request by disconnecting your internet and trying again?

Comment: Thanks for the comment.. When I look at the DevTools>Network tab in chrome it lists the data uri call as an HTTP GET request. It comes from the memory cache so it's not actually transferring data but this code is used to show a video camera preview every 1 second so and the backend guys asked if we can avoid the HTTP request.
Is there anyway to draw an image on a javascript canvas without using image.src =?